# Get generated source of an HTML page programmatically

Tags: html, webbrowser-control, extract

What is the easiest way to get the generated web page of a website programatically in any programming language?

The generated web page that is required is the one you get if you go to a web page in firefox and press Ctrl-a  and then right click and press "View Selection Source".

The one way that comes to mind is to understand the chromium [open source](https://github.com/chromium/chromium) web browser code and get the rendered page and use it in our service.

But I believe that there may be another solution out there that I am not aware of.

Comment: there are headless versions of both chrome and firefox. you can use/write a wrapper in your language of choice.

Comment: Thankx i am looking into it

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, you can get the full document content with

```
var html = document.documentElement.innerHTML;
```

Comment: I need to do this on a server. This is javascript on the browser i assume

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this server side you can use **file_get_contents()**

Ex:

```
 file_get_contents(path_to_webpage);
```

For reference:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_file_get_contents.asp